# Finding this limit

Tags: calculus

I am trying to help my younger brother with a question:

Find

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \big( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{2^k} \big) $$

Am I allowed to do $ \lim \sum = \sum \lim $? And then the limit would be $\infty$. Is this correct?

Comment: No, you are not allowed to do that. If I tell you that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n f(k) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty f(k)$, can you solve it then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't bring the limit into the sum because the limit is on the sum's extents.  What you *can* do is split the summation in two.
$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2^k}\right)&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^k}\right)\\&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^k}\\&=\infty-1=\infty\end{align}$$

Comment: Please note that you can't split the summation in two in the general case. If the two terms are the same and tend to $\infty$ the infinite sum is $0$ but you would get $\infty - \infty$.

Comment: It's true; however in such situations you can (I believe) generally re-join things that you will need to handle together.  Splitting works well to isolate individual terms, which often have more obvious non-summation-shaped results.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that the harmonic series $\sum_{k\ge1}\frac1k$ is divergent and the series $\sum_{k\ge1}\frac1{2^k}$ is geometric and convergent since the ratio $0\le\frac12<1$ so the given limit is $+\infty$.

Answer (score 5):

For $k\geq 1$, $2^k\geq 2k$, and thus $\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2^k}>\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2k}=\frac{1}{2k}$.

So: $$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2^k}\right) \geq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$$